# React Hooks Find by ID returning Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn react hooks, as it seems to be the way things will move going forward and I want to keep up with the times. I've been researching for hours trying to figure out exactly what is going on. In React Dev Tools, I'm not even seeing anything in component which leads me to believe that I am clearly inept and am not passing something correctly in my code. I'm really doing my best to get back into this, and I have exhausted my resources on YouTube, google, and Stack Overflow articles. I'm at the point where I'm at a loss and am breaking down asking for help lol.

The problem:

I'm trying to get one task from my back end with a simple GET by ID request. The error message is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function SingleTask (props) {
//Setting state
const initialTaskState = {
    _id: "",
    title: "",
    created_by: "",
    description: "",
    __v: 0
}

const [singleTask, setTask] = useState(initialTaskState)

//Axios GEt request to pull by ID from the DB
const fetchSingTask = (id) => {
    axios.get(`/api/tasks/${id}`, id)
    .then((res) => {
        setTask(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch (err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchSingTask(props.match.params.id)
}, [props.match.params.id]) 

return(
    <div>
        <h1>
            {singleTask.title}
        </h1>
    </div>
)
}

export default SingleTask;
```

I've tried multiple ways to pass in the ID, but nothing seems to work for me. I'm really at a loss, and I would appreciate any insight. I'm fairly confident that if I can get this working, I can figure out PUT and DELETE. I could get this done easily with Class Components, but I'm fairly new to this in general and would appreciate any insight.

EDIT for App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import AllTasks from './components/AllTasks';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';
import SingleTask from './components/SingleTask';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <AllTasks />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/create">
            <AddTask />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/task/:id">
            <SingleTask />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom`, and if so, how is this `SingleTask` rendered so it can receive any route props? It's really not any different than class-components. If you're within a routing context you'll more likely want to use the `useParams` React hook. If you are ***not*** using `react-router-dom` then please update your question to show us how you are passing props.

Comment: How does the `props` look like

Comment: I am using react-router-dom for App.js so that I can route everything accordingly. I guess my problem is I am not understanding at all how props works in this case and I am having trouble finding documentation on how this works with hooks. This isn't connecting with me, and I learn better by seeing how this works which is a problem as these conceptual examples provided on reacts website don't really help me figure this out. It's not a react problem, more so my learning method. Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way

Comment: Can you add App.js ?

Comment: @AlaHamadi There you go,

Comment: Removing props shows a state, but I'm returning everything instead of one by the ID itself

Comment: @Austin What is the output of ```console.log(props)```?

Comment: It returns an empty array @AyushGupta

Comment: Just an FYI, if you had changed to `<Route exact path="/task/:id" component={SingleTask} />` as per Giovanni's answer, your `SingleTask` component would have been passed route props and `props.match` would be defined. It doesn't matter class-component vs function component, they are both React components and both receive a `props` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `react-router` and React Hooks, then you should use `useParams()`.

Example - this is your route: `<Route exact path="/task/:id">`, So in this case, use `const { id } = useParams()`. Now, if you do `console.log(id)` , it will give you the exact id of the url.

**Solution:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"; //import useParams

function SingleTask (props) {
//Setting state
const initialTaskState = {
    _id: "",
    title: "",
    created_by: "",
    description: "",
    __v: 0
}
const { id } = useParams(); //it must equal with your url parameters ( :id )

const [singleTask, setTask] = useState(initialTaskState)

//Axios GEt request to pull by ID from the DB
const fetchSingTask = (id) => {
    axios.get(`/api/tasks/${id}`, id)
    .then((res) => {
        setTask(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch (err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchSingTask(id)
}, [id]) 

return(
    <div>
        <h1>
            {singleTask.title}
        </h1>
    </div>
)
}

export default SingleTask;
```

Read more about React Router and hooks [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)

Comment: This returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in 6110735e41306972c0fd1e34. I'm really lost as to what is going wrong at this point.

Comment: Also the component section of the React Dev Tools is blank, so I'm assuming nothing is actually being passed in

Comment: About React Dev Tools check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16840), and about that error: **GET** request should not have a body, try to change it like this: ```axios.get(`/api/tasks/${id}`)```and do the modification on the backend.

Comment: Somehow I missed switching 

axios.get(`/api/tasks/${id}`, id)

to

axios.get(`/api/tasks/${id}`)

That resolved everything, thank you!